# OS X Windows Remote Desktop Client cache location

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, cache

Where are the cache file(s) located for Windows Remote Desktop Client for Mac OS X? Specifically the "allow bitmap caching" setting is saving the bitmap files to the cache somewhere.

I'm running RDC version 2.0.1 (090714)

Comment: What problem are you experiencing that's prompting this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be `~/Library/Caches/remote desktop connection`.  This folder on my system contains BMC files, same as the ones in the `Terminal Services Client\Cache` folder in Windows.

Comment: My ~/Library/Caches does not have remote desktop connection

Comment: I am running RDC version 2.0.1 (090714) and I can confirm that I have a `~/Library/Caches/remote desktop connection` folder with a .bmc cache file contained therein.

Comment: Also confirmed with RDC version 2.0.0

Comment: Must be something about my system, or that it's not caching bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

For Remote Desktop Client 2.1.1 on OS X Mavericks, the bitmap cache file for 24-bit color depth is:

```
~/Library/Caches/remote\ desktop\ connection/bcache24.bmc
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space after that last backslash?

Comment: It was supposed to be a slash. Corrected.